# SMD button not in jlcpcb BOM

Tags: schematics, surface-mount, kicad, pcb-assembly

I want to try the jlcpcb assembly service.

I created the BOM, by using the `bom2grouped_csv_jlcpcb`. I inspected the generated file and indeed all the SMD components are here.
With one exception.
I intend to use this pushbutton:

https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/span-style-background-color-ff0-Tactile-span-Switches_XKB-Connectivity-TS-1101-C-W_C318938.html

However, this component in NOT in the csv list. How do I overcome this obstacle?

Comment: Jlc give you some options for externally sourced parts. Otherwise, if it’s not on their list, then it’s up to you to source and solder the part.

Comment: @Kartman but the button is on the jlcpcb website!